# ASP.NET Core MVC : this localhost page can’t be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Created a user controller with action methods. Right clicked on "Upsert" action method and added a view page.

Problem is when I go to browser with this URL

```
https://localhost:44318/Admin/User/Upsert
```

`userId` fetching but it shows an error

> This localhost page can't be found

Meanwhile my other action method properly working same controller like UserLock, User delete etc.

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public UserController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Upsert(string userId)
    {
        ........
        return View(objFromDb);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Upsert(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        .......
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this controller in an admin area, can you show the startup.cs?

Comment: Asp.net core MVC 5.0 @mason

Comment: Hi @SoumikMahajan, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0):

StartUp.cs

```
using BornoMala.DataAccess.Data;
using BornoMala.DataAccess.Repository;
using BornoMala.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using BornoMala.Utility;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BornoMala
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This localhost page can't be found

Please check if you organize your controllers and views in correct folder structure, like below.

[image]

And check if you associate the controller with an Area

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    //...
```

For more information about working with Areas in ASP.NET Core, you can check this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0#areas-for-controllers-with-views

Comment: Hi @SoumikMahajan, do you find the root cause of the issue?

Comment: `its return wrong datatype` So, can you share the actual solution to this issue?